# How to get response headers and body in dispatch request?

Tags: scala, http, header, request, scala-dispatch

I want to get both body and headers from dispatch request. How to do this?

```
val response = Http(request OK as.String)
for (r <- response) yield {
  println(r.toString) //prints body
  // println(r.getHeaders) // ???? how to print headers here ???? 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Dispatch docs:

> ```
> import dispatch._, Defaults._
> val svc = url("http://api.hostip.info/country.php")
> val country = Http(svc OK as.String)
> ```
>
> The above defines and initiates a request to the given host where 2xx
>   responses are handled as a string. Since Dispatch is fully
>   asynchronous, country represents a future of the string rather than
>   the string itself.
>   ([source](http://dispatch.databinder.net/Combined+Pages.html#Defining+requests))

In your example, the type of response is Future[String], because 'OK as.String' converts 2xx responses into strings and non-2xx responses into failed futures. If you remove 'OK as.String', you'll get a Future[com.ning.http.client.Response]. You can then use getResponseBody, getHeaders, etc. to inspect the Request object.

Answer (score 5):

We needed the response body of failed requests to an API, so we came up with this solution:

Define your own `ApiHttpError` class with `code` and `body` (for the body text):

```scala
case class ApiHttpError(code: Int, body: String)
  extends Exception("Unexpected response status: %d".format(code))
```

Define `OkWithBodyHandler` similar to what is used in the source of `displatch`:

```scala
class OkWithBodyHandler[T](f: Response => T) extends AsyncCompletionHandler[T] {
  def onCompleted(response: Response) = {
    if (response.getStatusCode / 100 == 2) {
      f(response)
    } else {
      throw ApiHttpError(response.getStatusCode, response.getResponseBody)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, near your call to the code that might throw and exception (calling `API`), add `implicit` override to the `ToupleBuilder` (again similar to the source code) and call `OkWithBody` on `request`:

```scala
class MyApiService {
  implicit class MyRequestHandlerTupleBuilder(req: Req) {
    def OKWithBody[T](f: Response => T) =
      (req.toRequest, new OkWithBodyHandler(f))
  }

  def callApi(request: Req) = {
    Http(request OKWithBody as.String).either
  }
}
```

From now on, fetching `either` will give you the `[Throwable, String]` (using `as.String)`, and the `Throwable` is our `ApiHttpError` with `code` and `body`.

Hope it helped.